# How to create a new column that is a modified version of an existing column in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a column of data that I've queried from a PostgreSQL server that contains the text form of twelve digit numbers, something like `012345678911` (there are often leading zeros which are important to preserve).

Is there a way for me to make a new column from this column that is simply the first 8 digits of every entry? So in the case of my example, I would like to create a column with the corresponding value `01234567`.

I'm currently trying to use the conditional column function, but I don't know how to or if I can modify the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using Power Query (click on Transform Data/Edit Queries from your home tab in Power BI) as below.

[image]